# How can I translate douyin.com?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, chinese, google-translate

When I attempt to translate douyin.com from Chinese to English with the Google Translate browser extension by clicking "Translate Page", nothing happens. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-way-to-set-Douyin-in-English): "Douyin (抖音) is intended for the Chinese market and was not designed for an international audience, though there are foreigners and foreign companies that have accounts on Douyin. There is currently **no method to change the language of Douyin into English**."

Since the site appears to be implemented as **graphic** files, rather than in Chinese characters, you **can** translate it, albeit *slowly*:

1. Take a screenshot of a page or portion of a page.

[image: Douyin page screenshot]

2. Submit the screenshot to optical character recognition (OCR), such as [EasyScreenOCR](https://online.easyscreenocr.com/Home/ChineseOCR) or [an alternative](https://www.cisdem.com/resource/best-chinese-ocr-software.html).
3. *Now* take the text, in Chinese, and submit it to a translation program, such as [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/):

[image: Google Translation]

Comment: Why can't google translate just get the text from its html data and translate it, like it does with other sites?

Comment: Because it **doesn't use text**, at least on the first screen; **it uses images (AKA pictures, graphics) of text**. as stated in the answer above.

Comment: I looked at the html, and there was text. And google translate wouldn't translate it.

Comment: Did you copy the text, and then paste it into Google Translate??

Comment: There being text does not mean it is part of the visibly rendered portion of the page, and the translation tools work only on the visibly rendered portions of the page. The text could be alt-text, for accessibility purposes, or to aid in search engine indexing, or other factors. The fact the site specifically states it will not be translated trumps your wish to translate it using an automated tool.

Comment: @music2myear No, it was rendered text all right.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Well that works but it's slow and defeats the purpose. The google translate extension should be translating the text, but it's not.